# get value from text field in autoit

Tags: swing, testing, autoit

I want to get the value from a text field of a swing application in Autoit for comparing. Is there any tool for finding ID of specific field like firebug in browsers. And what is the code in Autoit for extracting and comparing a field value.

Answer (score 0):

From the help file:

```
; *******************************************************
; Example 1 - Open a browser to the basic example, get an object reference
;               to the DIV element with the ID "line1". Display the innerText
;               of this element to the console.
; *******************************************************

#include <IE.au3>

Local $oIE = _IE_Example("basic")
Local $oDiv = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "line1")
ConsoleWrite(_IEPropertyGet($oDiv, "innertext") & @CRLF)
```

In order to get the value you can use

```
 _IEPropertyGet($oDiv, "value") 
or
 $oDiv.Value
```

Comment: I want to get ID of a field in swing application. Is there any application for that?

Answer (score 0):

[This UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/87956-java-udf/) provides automation support for Java applications.

Example usage:

```
WinActivate("Piface Application Selector")
_JavaAttachAndWait("Piface Application Selector")
$java_obj1 = _JavaObjValueGet("", "Type of analysis", "label")
$java_obj2 = _JavaObjValueGet("", "Run dialog", "push button")
MsgBox(262144, "_JavaObjValueGet.au3",  "Object values in the Piface Application Selector window include:" & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
```

Comment: OK _JavaObjValueGet is the function but how can I specify that field?

Comment: Use Autoit Window Info tool found under autoit installation folder.